# SQLAlchemy - bulk insert ignore: "Duplicate entry"

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a table named `user_data`, the column `id` and `user_id` as the unique key. I want to import some history data to this table. I use [bulk_insert_mappings](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_insert_mappings) method to batch insert data. But  there are errors as below:

> IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062, u"Duplicate entry '1-1234' for key 'idx_on_id_and_user_id'")

How to ignore this error and discard duplicate data when batch insert?

Comment: please check your models, you might have been entering the similar value in the primary key or unique key field that is causing the problem

Comment: I know there are duplicate value, but I cannot change the history data, I just want to ignore the error and insert operation continue, just like mysql `insert ignore...` statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dealing with duplicate primary keys on insert in SQLAlchemy (declarative style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322514/dealing-with-duplicate-primary-keys-on-insert-in-sqlalchemy-declarative-style)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should handle every error. But if you really want to just ignore all errors, you can't really do a bulk insert. Sometimes there will be integrity errors in the actual data you are importing.  You have to insert one by one and ignore. I would only use this in once off scripts.

```
for item in dict_list:
    try:
        session.merge(orm(**item))
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
```

Comment: Shouldn't merge already work without any exceptions? Note that both merge and rollback make inserts very slow

Comment: Using session.commit() for every single item in a large list causes extremely heavy I/O and poor performance.

Comment: Preprocessing the data and fixing the errors before inserting is always first prize. Without knowing that upfront there are still often use cases where you just want to get at least of the data in the database. Eg before a demo, then performance really does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sqlalchemy core API to do large bulk inserts, but it gets database specific. For [those using postgres](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.Insert.on_conflict_do_nothing), it looks like this:

```py
rows = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "foo"},
    {"id": 1, "name": "foo-dupe"},
]

stmt = insert(YourTableName).values(rows)
stmt = stmt.on_conflict_do_nothing(
    index_elements=["id_or_column_causing_integrity_error", "colB"]
)
db.session.execute(stmt)
db.session.commit()
```

Note that the value of `index_elements` takes a list with one or more names of the columns that make up the unique index you want to ignore.